# Is it smart to switch off bt/gps/wifi on app exit?

Tags: android, bluetooth, gps, wifi

I have an Android app that deals with GPS data. When a user starts it, it offers to turn on the GPS.

Is it smart (or is it bad) if I code the app to automatically **turn off** the GPS when a user closes the app?

What about automatically turning off Wi-Fi or Bluetooth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since about Android 1.6, it has not been possible to turn GPS off/on programatically. All you can do is launch the system preference screen, which does allow the user to disable/enable it for all applications.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it. That's why most apps don't have it :). I'll check up if anything changed in v3.0.

Comment: You were right. It's not possible to turn it on automatically. The only way is to open GPS/Wifi settings and let user activate it manually.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is different for every user, so let users choose: On the messagebox that asks to turn on the GPS etc just add a checkbox saying "turn these off when exiting the application" that people can check before accepting.

Comment: Well, I know I always have two options: pop-up or settings. Pop-ups are irritating, and settings are 'invisible' to most users (users don't like to deal with it). That's why I asked such question. Thanks anyway

Comment: Ofc but you said you already offer to turn on the GPS, I assumed that was a popup (and I would strongly recommend a popup since user will not understand why your app isnt working when the GPS is turned off) And since you already have 1 popup you can easily add a checkbox to it.

Comment: As a user, I would hate an app to silently disable features of my phone without informing me or providing an option.

Comment: @dave It's happening only when you exit the app. I think it's better that way than finding in battery usage that my app has drained your battery because the GPS was on :).

Comment: askmo: But what if I use other apps that require GPS? I don't want to have one app breaking another app because it thinks I don't want GPS on. The user knows best.